# Number of stereoisomers of 1-(2-methylcyclohexyl)ethan-1-ol

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

[image: 1-(2-methylcyclohexyl)ethan-1-ol]

How many stereoisomers are possible for the compound in the picture? I tried to draw a rough picture and indicated the chiral carbons. I'm getting 8 stereoisomers are possible but my book gives the answer as 2. Can someone explain where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I'm wondering this as well - the only other interpretation I can see is if you had to specify how many **types** of stereoisomers there are. That would give 2, because you'd have diastereomers and enantiomers but not meso compounds.

Comment: Can't there be geometrical isomerism ?

Comment: Geometrical Isomerism doesn't apply in this case since there are no double bonds.

Comment: But one could be above the plane and one below...there need not be a double bond

Comment: True, but that would not change the name of the compound regardless of whether the particular group in question takes an axial or Equatorial position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments on the question are incorrect *[edit: the offending comments seem to be gone now]*, as is the answer given in the book. In general, answers printed at the back of a book should never be taken as the absolute truth. There are typos in all books. Even well-known and well-written textbooks have many errata (usually corrected in subsequent printings).

As you said, there are three chiral centres and therefore 8 stereoisomers.

There are no other elements of symmetry present in this molecule which render any of those 8 stereoisomers equivalent.